# Выбор конкретного сообщения из очереди rabbitmq

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

Имеем:  2 очереди - messages и error_messages, при ошибке сообщение падает в error_message, у каждого сообщения есть уникальный ID.

Бизнес процесс  такой: администратор мониторит error_messages, делает правки по конкретному сообщению и обратно перезапускает обработку переместив конкретное сообщение обратно в очередь messages.

Сейчас  это реализовано в MsSql.

Вопрос: Возможно ли  в rabbitmq,  перенести только одно сообщение из одной очереди в другую?

p.s. Есть команда Move messages, но она переносит все сообщения, что расточительно, нужно перенести только одно сообщение.

Comment: а его нельзя просто ещё раз опубликовать в нужную очередь?

Comment: Можно, но тогда будет аналогичная задача – удалить конкретное сообщение из очереди error_message.

Comment: ну вы же извлекаете его из очереди для обработки, он больше не остается в ней, или я не так понял вас

Comment: Спасибо что интересуетесь моим вопросом. Дело в том, что из tutorials rabbitmq, для каждой очереди есть обработчик(и), и он обрабатывает все сообщения из очереди. А вопрос можно ли вытащить конкретное сообщения, каким то образом. Теоретически можно поставить в обработчике условие если содержит сообщение под определенным ID => изъять из очереди, но тогда получим бесконечный трафик от error_queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Логично сделать что-то типа:

Администратор читает сообщение из очереди с ошибками указывая requeue: false. Далее в зависимости от ситуации сообщение нужно отправить либо обратно в эту же очередь или в другую очередь с задачами.

Можно сделать это автоматизированно, при возникновении ошибки, сообщение попадает в dead letter exchange (DLX), так оно по routing key попадает в очередь в которой может пролежать столько сколько нужно, а потом само вернуться в очередь с задачами, это удобно при возникновении временных ошибок и необходимости гарантии доставки сообщений. Плюс ко всему удобно мониторить очередь отстойника (если она начала расти, то что-то пошло не так).

Подробнее о DLX можно почитать тут:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html

https://habr.com/ru/post/235505/

Comment: Наиболее близкий к вопросу ответ. Меня осенило, очередь на то и очередь чтобы выдавать сообщения последовательно, нельзя просто так сказать "Эй ты сообщение под номером 101 иди на обработку"(в бд такое возможно поменяв значение столбца, но таблицы БД и очередь это разная структура данных)

Answer (score 0):

Очередь на то и очередь чтобы выдавать сообщения последовательно, нельзя просто так сказать "Эй ты сообщение под номером 101 иди на обработку".В БД такое возможно поменяв значение столбца, но таблицы БД и очередь это разная структура данных.